# Android: Universal Image Loader and the blank space issue

Tags: java, android, html, universal-image-loader

i have a string that contains `HTML` contents (text and images), i'm using the [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to translate the `<img>` html tags to be displayed 
correctly in a TextView, each image in its original place in the paragraph.

Everything works fine except that i get a blank extra space at the end of the TextView after the images get rendered.

The more the images the more the extra space.

[image: This is the demo]

And there's a lot of blank space under what i'm showing here in the picture.

Here's a [link](http://ana.fm/api/article/846328644526560) to see the HTML string if that helps, the string that i'm using is "description".

And here's the `string`:

```
desc = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.single_article_desc);
String ar_desc = json.getString("description");    
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(ar_desc,new UILImageGetter(desc, getActivity()), null);
desc.setText(spanned);
```

And here's the `UILImageGetter.java` that i'm using:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

public class UILImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {
    Context c;
    TextView container;
    UrlImageDownloader urlDrawable;

    public UILImageGetter(View textView, Context context) {
        this.c = context;
        this.container = (TextView) textView;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        urlDrawable = new UrlImageDownloader(c.getResources(), source);
        urlDrawable.drawable = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(source, new SimpleListener(urlDrawable));
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    private class SimpleListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {
        UrlImageDownloader urlImageDownloader;

        public SimpleListener(UrlImageDownloader downloader) {
            super();
            urlImageDownloader = downloader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
            int height = loadedImage.getHeight();

            int newWidth = width;
            int newHeight = height;

            if (width > container.getWidth()) {
                newWidth = container.getWidth();
                newHeight = (newWidth * height) / width;
            }

            if (view != null) {
                view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
                view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            }

            Drawable result = new BitmapDrawable(c.getResources(), loadedImage);
            result.setBounds(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            urlImageDownloader.setBounds(1, 1, newWidth, newHeight);
            urlImageDownloader.drawable = result;
            Log.e("new height", String.valueOf(container.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));// Log the new height to Logcat
            container.setHeight((container.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));
            container.invalidate();
        }
    }

    private class UrlImageDownloader extends BitmapDrawable {
        public Drawable drawable;

        public UrlImageDownloader(Resources res, String filepath) {
            super(res, filepath);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, filepath);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the error logs for the new height from the Logcat:

```
02-25 17:11:28.203    2563-2563/com.example.navigationdrawer E/new height﹕ 2363
02-25 17:11:28.631    2563-2563/com.example.navigationdrawer E/new height﹕ 3038
02-25 17:11:28.719    2563-2563/com.example.navigationdrawer E/new height﹕ 3713
02-25 17:11:32.620    2563-2563/com.example.navigationdrawer E/new height﹕ 4388
02-25 17:11:32.820    2563-2563/com.example.navigationdrawer E/new height﹕ 5063
02-25 17:11:34.024    2563-2563/com.example.navigationdrawer E/new height﹕ 5738
```

Anyone can Help ?

Comment: could you debug and check what value the container.setHeight((container.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));
gets?

I would start looking there

Comment: I edited my question, can you please check again ? @EvripidisDrakos

Comment: first of all, dont use getIntrinsicHeight(), this will return the actual height, not the new one you use. Just use getHeight()

Comment: Well, i solved the problem, i'll put the answer

Comment: Can you upvote my answer :) i was looking all day to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done by replacing

```
container.setHeight((container.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));
```

With

```
container.setHeight((container.getHeight() + newHeight));
```

Thanks @Evripidis Drakos